# Frame and Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm studying Python 3.x on a book from APOGEO, by Kenneth A. Lambert.
On some exercise I found some errors (think due to some changes in tkinter).

Here is the example:

```
from tkinter import *

class provaFinestra(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Imposta finestra e suoi oggetti"""
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Finestra di Prova")
        self.grid()
        self._label = Label(self, text = "Ciao Mondo")
        self._label.grid()

    def main():
        """istanzia e visualizza la finestra"""
        wind = provaFinestra().mainloop
```

when I run the code I get the following error:

```
the name 'provaFinestra' is not  defined.
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: place your main function out of class

Answer (score 1):

you should place main out of class

```
from tkinter import *

class provaFinestra(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Imposta finestra e suoi oggetti"""
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Finestra di Prova")
        self.grid()
        self._label = Label(self, text = "Ciao Mondo")
        self._label.grid()

def main():
    """istanzia e visualizza la finestra"""
    wind = provaFinestra().mainloop
main()
```

Comment: response with main() is not defined